# Unhandled rejection error: invalid input syntax for integer: "true" Express + passport + postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, passport.js, knex.js

Can someone tell me what the heck is going on? Im trying to make a simple login page, I'm using knex with postreSQL and I'm getting a weird error I cannot understand:

```
Unhandled rejection error: invalid input syntax for integer: "true"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/idlesolution/Desktop/backend/user/user/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/idlesolution/Desktop/backend/user/user/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:379:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/idlesolution/Desktop/backend/user/user/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Here is my code. First, I do the post request and authenticate it with passport:

```
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/user/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/',

}))
```

And then I setup a local strategy in my server.js file:

```
passport.use(new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    knex('users').select('password').where({username: username}).then((data) => {
        if(data.length === 0){
            return done(null, false)
        } else{

            return done(null, true);
        }
    })
}))
```

The error hits when I type the info of existing user, so its in the else block. When I change true to a random string the error is still there, however, if I change it to false there is no error but obviously I dont wanna leave it that way

Comment: Try removing the `return` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are returning `true` after user is found where you should be returning a `user` itself. This `user` object will be then used to `serialize` and on subsequent requests, `deserialize` the user. Also, you should try to fetch `id`(along with password) of the user which you can use for serialization.

So your code should look something like this

```
passport.use(new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    knex('users').select('id', 'password').where({username: username}).then((data) => {
        if(data.length === 0){
            return done(null, false)
        } else {
            return done(null, data);
        }
    });
}));
```